# Proving First Order Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> An equation of motion when a particle moves in a resting medium is given by
>   $$
> \tfrac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}t}
> =
> -(kv+bt)
> $$
>   where $k$ and $b$ are constants.
>   Given that $v=u$ when $t=0$, show that
>   $$
> v(t)
> =
> \tfrac{b}{k^2}
> -
> \tfrac bkt
> +
> \left(u-\tfrac{b}{k^2}\right)e^{-kt}
> $$

Answer (score 1):

$$v'(t)=bt-kv(t)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\text{d}v(t)}{\text{d}t}=bt-kv(t)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\text{d}v(t)}{\text{d}t}+kv(t)=bt\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $\mu(t)=e^{\int k\space\text{d}t}=e^{kt}$:

---

$$e^{kt}\cdot\frac{\text{d}v(t)}{\text{d}t}+\left(e^{kt}k\right)v(t)=e^{kt}bt\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(e^{kt}v(t)\right)=e^{kt}bt\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(e^{kt}v(t)\right)\space\text{d}t=\int e^{kt}bt\space\text{d}t\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{kt}v(t)=\frac{be^{kt}(kt-1)}{k^2}+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$v(t)=\frac{bt}{k}-\frac{b}{k^2}+\text{C}e^{-kt}$$

Comment: You've taken V=u as a function of 't', right?